# Spring AMQP - MessageListenerAdapter - pass additional arguments

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

To create a SimpleMessageListenerContainer, I do something like this.

```
SimpleMessageConsumer simpleMessageConsumer = new SimpleMessageConsumer();

MessageListenerAdapter adapter =
    new CustomMessageListenerAdapater(simpleMessageConsumer);
adapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("consume");
adapter.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());

SimpleMessageListenerContainer
    container =
    new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);

container.setMessageListener(adapter);
```

My SimpleMessageConsumer

```
  public void consume(String message){
      log.info(message);
}
```

I noticed in the spring-amqp-refrence that the "***annotated
listener endpoint infrastructure***" allows you to conveniently pass additional Message properties into your consumer like so :

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
public void processOrder(Order order, @Header("order_type") String orderType) {
...
}
```

Can that be done using consumer creation approach I mention above? I want to access to some of the headers of the Message object. I know that I can make my consumer implement the MessageListener or the ChannelAwareMessageListener and have access to the entire Message object.  However, I dont want the whole Message object, since I like the convenience of using the  ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter with the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter to do conversion to my desired type(in my real app), before my consumer delegated method is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `MessagingMessageConverter` with the `payloadConverter` as the mentioned `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` and then in your `CustomMessageListenerAdapater` you override there a:

```
/**
 * Build an array of arguments to be passed into the target listener method. Allows for multiple method arguments to
 * be built from a single message object.
 * <p>
 * The default implementation builds an array with the given message object as sole element. This means that the
 * extracted message will always be passed into a <i>single</i> method argument, even if it is an array, with the
 * target method having a corresponding single argument of the array's type declared.
 * <p>
 * This can be overridden to treat special message content such as arrays differently, for example passing in each
 * element of the message array as distinct method argument.
 * @param extractedMessage the content of the message
 * @return the array of arguments to be passed into the listener method (each element of the array corresponding to
 * a distinct method argument)
 */
protected Object[] buildListenerArguments(Object extractedMessage) {
```

casting that `extractedMessage` to the `Message<?>` and extract desired headers if that.

Comment: Thank you @Artem as you suggested

    MessagingMessageConverter messagingMessageConverter =
            new MessagingMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter(),         new SimpleAmqpHeaderMapper());


and inside of my CustomMessageListenerAdapater

      protected Object[] buildListenerArguments(Object extractedMessage) {
        
        MessageProperties messageProperties =
            ((Message) extractedMessage).getMessageProperties();
    
        return new Object[]{extractedMessage, messageProperties};
    
      }

Comment: OK. That's fine, too.

Comment: No, that's not. The `MessagingMessageConverter` returns an `org.springframework.messaging.Message` instance. So, your `buildListenerArguments()` should deal with that type instead.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the right direction. Appreciate your quick and thoughtful response! I posted my final solution below.

Comment: Will make sure to do that next time

Answer (score 3):

```
public class CustomMessageListenerAdapter extends MessageListenerAdapter {



 public CustomMessageListenerAdapter(Object delegate) {
    super(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  protected Object invokeListenerMethod(String methodName, Object[] arguments,
      Message originalMessage) throws Exception {


    Object[] modifiedArguments = new Object[arguments.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(arguments, 0, modifiedArguments,
                     0, arguments.length);

    //add the original message with headers
    modifiedArguments[arguments.length] = originalMessage;

    return super.invokeListenerMethod(methodName, modifiedArguments, originalMessage);
  }

}
```

and my Message consumer now has an additional argument - the original message

```
public class SimpleMessageConsumer {


  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleMessageConsumer.class);


  public void consume(String messageConverted, Message originalMessage){
    log.info(originalMessage.toString());
  }

}
```

My Bean Configuration looks something like this:

```
SimpleMessageConsumer simpleMessageConsumer = new SimpleMessageConsumer();

    MessageListenerAdapter adapter =
        new CustomMessageListenerAdapter(simpleMessageConsumer);
    adapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("consume");
    adapter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());

//container
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer
        container =
        new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);

    container.setMessageListener(adapter);
```

Comment: setMessageListener(Object) is deprecated as of 2020